# What does the revision in the CLR v4.0.30319 encode?

Tags: .net, clr, revision

My understanding is that the revision of "50727" in the v2.0 of the CLR encodes the date of the release build: 2005-07-27. If this is true, what does the 30319 encode?

Note: my information comes from a blog of a member of the CLR team. Note 2nd comment on this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/10/28/486189.aspx.

Comment: # of kittens died in the process...

Comment: @Diadistis: Great! v4.0 really _is_ better than v2.0. Unless, of course, you count the kitteh deaths cumulatively.

Comment: Hmmm, as a cat lover I insist on a petition to change # of kittens died to...uh...# of pizza slices consumed in late night coding sessions!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a range of timestamps on the .NET 4.0 files that span about 20 hours.  The build ended early in the morning on March 19th, 2010 (UTC).  So the 0319 part of the version is a very good match.  The simple explanation is that year 0 for .NET 4.0 was 2007.  Sounds about right for them starting to work on it.

Answer (score 2):

Version 2.0 of the CLR was released on 2005-11-07. The revision number encodes nothing - it's just that, a revision number.

Comment: I didn't mean "release" of the framework. I meant "release build". I updated my question, and believe this answer is incorrect.